# Problem with my mvc app isnt using style.css

Tags: css, spring, model-view-controller

Im trying to configure style css file with my mvc app. Everything is working well except that pages dont use style.css. Im doing it first time and i dont know how it should look like but i did this with internet. Where is a problem? :/

App config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("spring")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());


@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    return viewResolver;
}
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Head JSP file

```
<head>
<title>Site under construction</title>
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>'>
</head>
```

Path to css file
\src\main\resources\css\style.css

Comment: Please do provide your code in form of code snippets, not pictures.

Comment: Yea sorry my bad just it's my first post here. Thanks for tip

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the debug tools in your browser (F12 generally).  You will most likely see a 404 for that file (missing).  Check out what URL the browser is trying to pull the resource from.  Most likely it's looking somewhere you aren't expecting.

Comment: There isn't any error in console tab :/ And when i tried set up manualy add css file in tab style editor i got this error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: i just saw warning in firefox "style sheet could not be loaded". it could be fault my firefox?

Comment: I tested in IE and there is the same problem